# Java ProcessBuilder: good way to close redirectOutput file (Java 8)

Tags: java, process, stream

I launch process and kill him in my app.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
        .directory(dir)
        .command(command)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .redirectOutput(file);
```

and killing with

```
void kill(Process p) {
    Process kill = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "pkill -TERM -P " + pid).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
    kill.waitFor();
    if (p != null) {
        if (p.isAlive()) {
            p.destroy();
        }
    }
    try {
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Util.errorLogger.error(e, "can't close log");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I properly close file's streams so that there won't be .fuse_hidden00123bd3nnnnn file?

P.s. `pkill` because I can't kill `bash -c` children otherwise

P.s.s. Only Java 8 can be used

Comment: Perform tidy up code as required in the launcher not the killer as that is when the killed process output streams would be ended. Each time you use `ProcessBuilder` you only need to cleanup it own sub-process after `waitFor()` ends.

Comment: @DuncG, I also can have commands like `bash -c` and when i tried `p.destroy()` on them children didn't die

Comment: You've not shown the launch + its cleanup code so it isn't obvious what handling you've got after calling `launch.waitFor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all child process to be killed with:

```
p.destroy();
p.descendants().forEach(ProcessHandle::destroy);
```

Note that IO stream cleanup is best left to the code that started the sub-process once the corresponding `waitFor()` was completed.

Comment: Yeah, it is really good answer for elder Java. Sorry for not mentioning about Java 8